# Get reference of Top constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, safearealayoutguide

I am trying to get the reference of topConstraint (eg: attached) of a given view, associated with safe area - top.

[image]

I have created a function which works fine, but, logically not reliable.

```
func getSafeAreaTopConstraint(view: UIView, in targetView: UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
    let constraints = targetView.constraints.filter({ $0.firstItem as? UIView == view || $0.secondItem as? UIView == view })
    return constraints.filter({ $0.firstAttribute == .top || $0.secondAttribute == .top }).first
}
```

I would like to create a function which compares as follows

```
func getSafeAreaTopConstraint(view: UIView, in targetView: UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
    let constraints = targetView.constraints.filter({ ($0.firstItem as? UIView == view && $0.secondItem == SafeArea.Top) || ($0.secondItem as? UIView == view && $0.firstItem == SafeArea.Top) })
    return constraints.filter({ $0.firstAttribute == .top || $0.secondAttribute == .top }).first
}
```

How do I compare if the `firstItem` or `secondItem` is `Safe Area.Top`?

Comment: IBOUtlet, make a conection with your code, you can also get it by constraint identifier

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have attached the screenshot for an understanding. I m trying to get it programmatically for any given view.

Comment: You need to add the constraint in the storyboard or xib manually anyway right?

Comment: I have to do some adjustment in topConstraint of given view associated with `SafeArea.Top`. Thats why I am trying to get the reference.

Comment: I think is pointless this kind of function if you want to have a reference to all your views top constraints, you need to put an identifier on it or make it a Outlet when is created manually in the storyboard, if you are making this change later on your code or someone's code this will be painful but is the only way, or at least the only way i know to do it, firstAttribute and secondAttribute is not reliable for comparison

Comment: btw if you find another reliable way please post it as answer, will be helpful and interesting happy coding

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing, by accessing the `constraints` field is not safe. The recommended approach is creating an IBOutlet for the constraint